# Filtrar datos en React JS para barra de búsqueda

Tags: json, nodejs, reactjs, firebase, filtro

Estoy intentando hacer una barra de búsqueda para una app de vuelos, en la que se filtre por:
Origen:
Destino:
Fecha:
Disponibilidad:

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer que cuando el usuario ingresa el Origen, en el caso de "JFK" al estar repetido, luego me indique los destinos a donde hay vuelos disponibles.

Ejemplo: Al ingresar "JFK" se pide que destinos están disponibles para ese origen, y debería indicar "SVO" y "BOG", con su fecha disponible.

Tengo este JSON:

```
    [
      {
        "availability": 5,
        "data": "2020-11-15",
        "origin": "JFK",
        "destination": "SVO",
        "price": 1200.50
      },
      {
        "availability": 3,
        "data": "2020-11-15",
        "origin": "JFK",
        "destination": "BOG",
        "price": 197.68
      },
      {
        "availability": 1,
        "data": "2020-11-15",
        "origin": "CDG",
        "destination": "MAD",
        "price": 300.3
      }
    ]
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Este script busca cupo para 2 personas para el viaje buscado.

```
const json_vuelos = [
  {
    "availability": 5,
    "data": "2020-11-15",
    "origin": "JFK",
    "destination": "SVO",
    "price": 1200.50
  },
  {
    "availability": 3,
    "data": "2020-11-15",
    "origin": "JFK",
    "destination": "BOG",
    "price": 197.68
  },
  {
    "availability": 1,
    "data": "2020-11-15",
    "origin": "CDG",
    "destination": "MAD",
    "price": 300.3
  }
];

//TUS FILTROS DE BÚSQUEDA
const filters = { origin: "JFK", destination: "SVO", availability: 2 };

//Recorremos con un filter los resultados.
const vuelos = json_vuelos.filter((item) => {
  //Filter devolverá el elemento solo si hay una respuesta positiva (TRUE) en las condiciones
  for (let key in filters) {
    if (item[key] === undefined) return false;
    switch (key) {
      case "availability":
        if (item[key] < filters[key]) return false;
        break;
      case "data":
      case "origin":
      case "destination":
        if (item[key] != filters[key]) return false;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(vuelos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Me gustaría hacer una página de vuelos, pero todavía no me queda claro como realizar las búsquedas con los filtros.

Comment: Pues tendrás unos inputs o selectores con los filtros. Luego metes en un objeto como el que te mostre `filters` y esos los usas para filtrar iterando el resultado. Aunque si de verdad quieres hacer una página de vuelos, la verdad es que deberías hacer algo escalable y los filtros se debería procesar en backend.